# how to import function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

AppFunction.js

```
export default function myFunction() {
  var str1 = "Hello ";
  var str2 = "world!";
  var res = str1.concat(str2);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import myFunction  from './AppFunction';

class App extends Component {           
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I should to import an existing JavaScript library and then call it's functions.

```
componentDidMount() {
  myFunction()
}
```

When I write like this, working. But shows on screen without clicking the onclick button. I want to press the button and show it on the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

to

```
<button onClick={myFunction}>Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
export default function myFunction() {
  var str1 = "Hello ";
  var str2 = "world!";
  var res = str1.concat(str2);
  return res;
}
```

and

```
<button onClick={myFunction}>Try it</button>
```